# where() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have three arrays, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. I want to put in `res` and element of `X` in case the corresponding element from `Z` is true; otherwise, I will put an element from `Y`.

I implemented it like this:

```
X = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Y = tf.constant([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
Z = tf.constant([[True, False], [False, True]], tf.bool)
res = tf.where(Z, X, Y)
print(res.eval())
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I looked at the definiton of `tf.where` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) and my usage seems fine.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: can you try `tf.where(Z, x=X, y=Y)`

Comment: Your code works fine with TensorFlow 1.0.1, so I'm curious: which TF version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using an old version of TensorFlow:

e.g. in r0.10 `tf.where` used to take only 2 arguments.

`tf.where(input, name=None)`

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops/sequence_comparison_and_indexing#where

Comment: I'm using `0.8.0`, probably because I installed it with `pip`.

Comment: That makes sense then. You should probably install the latest version: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/